# Unable to inset N-gon face

Tags: modeling, workflow, faces

I am trying to inset N-gon face but failing.

Create cube. Delete top and bottom faces.

[image]

Add separation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> so that it is not in the middle of a face:

[image]

Fill top hole with <kbd>F</kbd>. It will be a 5-gon. Select it and start *inset*

[image]

Make it smaller than the distance between center and additional separation. Dithering begin.

Is n-gon prohibited situation? How to fix out of it?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what the problem is without being able to directly examine the mesh, but I would guess double vertices are the culprits. Try pressing M to merge by distance with everything selected or just delete the top face and remake it.

Comment: This top face looks like an ngon.  Hiserod's suggestion should work

Comment: @HISEROD no, merging didn't do anything and didn't help

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your mesh or Blender. It's just how the inset function (or the math behind it) works. Blender creates parallel edges that are going to overlap when the inset starts overlapping the parallel edge of the additional loop. A possible fix: Inset the face to the point where the vertices start to overlap, merge them into one vertex, then inset the resulting face further, if needed.

Comment: metaphor_set's suggestion would work well or you could use extrude and scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of filling the face and insetting, you can extrude the edge with <kbd>E</kbd> and scale it down by pressing <kbd>S</kbd> afterward.

[image]